# How do I pass the same state to multiple routes using react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to pass the same state to multiple `Routes` using `react-router`.  Here is my `router` setup.

```
var routes = (
  <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
    <Route name="step1" handler={Step1} />
    <Route name="step2" handler={Step2} />
    <Route name="step3" handler={Step3} />
  </Route>
);
```

I want to pass to my `route` which step I am on.  I tried using the `path=":step"`, but then I don't route properly.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Basically you have subroutes here so in the render of app try <RouteHandler yourprop="yourprop" \> and each shbroute will receive it as props

Answer (score 0):

The result of `router.run` returns the `Handler` and a `state` prop. You can look a the `state` prop to check what route you're on. Like this...

```
Router.run(..., function(Handler, state) {
    console.log(state); //see what's available here
    var step = state.getPath();
    React.render(<Handler step={step} />);
}
```

[Router Run - State](http://rackt.github.io/react-router/#Router.run)